# JQuery - On change, append to $(this).find div

Tags: jquery

**Goal:**
How do I correctly append a value to a div, based on a changed state/value in the select box.

I know that I can manipulate the div directly via: $('added_options').append

But assuming that I might have multiple classes named 'box#' with the same content as below, I would only like to change what is within the selected div, not all.

*(This is a relatively simple question. I am assuming I am misinterpreting the way that $(this).find() works in respect to the on 'change' event.)*

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.box1').on('change', '.select_option', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).find('.added_options').append("test");
        });
    })
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box1">
    <select class="select_option">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="add_option">Add Option</button>
    <div class="added_options">
        <!--Added options-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.added_options` is not a children of the `.select_option` element.

Use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
$(this).parents('.box1') //first find its parent
 .find('.added_options').append("test");
```

You may also use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targetting the `select` elemetn using event delegation, `this` inside the handler refers to the `select` element, since `added_options` is not a descendant of the select element `$(this).find('.added_options')` won't be there

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.box1').on('change', '.select_option', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').find('.added_options').append("test");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
  <select class="select_option">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="add_option">Add Option</button>
  <div class="added_options">
    <!--Added options-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.box1').on('change', '.select_option', function(e){
   // no need of preventing here 
   $(this).closest('div.box1').find('.added_options').append("test");
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.box1').on('change', '.select_option', function(e) {
    // no need of preventing here 
    $(this).closest('div.box1').find('.added_options').append(this.value+" test<br/>");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
  <select class="select_option">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="add_option">Add Option</button>
  <div class="added_options">
    <!--Added options-->
  </div>
</div>
```